# Pywinauto - Control Identifiers disappear when running the same command

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I'm looking at control identifiers to create an automation script and noticed that the first time I ran `print_control_identifiers()`, I had `DataItems` that showed up.  However, any time after that when running the same `print_control_identifiers()` command, all the controls showed up except for the `DataItems`.

**Code:**

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(best_match="ARMOR CRITICAL")
app.window(control_type="Window").child_window(control_type="Document").print_control_identifiers()
```

**Output** - first pass

[image]

**Output** - second pass

[image]

I've been using the uia backend every time.

I'm using `Python 3.7.4` and `pywinauto 0.6.8`

Comment: Because it is different table found. `.print_control_identifiers()` is a method of WindowSpecification. It performs search for subtree root element every time it is called. So `Table3` is different than `Table2`, of course. Try to add more specific search criteria to `window()` and `child_window()` keywords.